# What does “ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs” do?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, icacls, winsxs

Originally posted by me on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692509/what-does-icacls-c-windows-winsxs-do), reposted here because this seems like a more relevant site for this question. Some wording has been slightly edited and more information has been added.

When typing "icacls /?" into Windows command prompt, the documentation doesn't seem to explain what "icacls <folder/file>" does. According to [docs.windows.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls), the parameter "<filename>" "Specifies the file for which to display DACLs" and "<directory>" "Specifies the directory for which to display DACLs". According to [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html), the command "icacls "C:\demo\example"" is used to "View the permissions currently set on a folder".

Now, what is confusing, is that in [an article](https://www.troubleshootingcentral.com/fix-windows-resource-protection-could-not-perform-the-requested-operation-sfc-scannow-error-message/) which instructs how to solve a SFC /scannow windows resource protection issue, the 3rd repair suggestion, "Modify Security Descriptors in WinSXS Folder", suggests to use the command "ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs" as a possible fix for the issue. The site tells about the background of why it might fix the issue:

"A lot of your Windows system updates and system files are stored in the WinSXS folder, and if your SFC utility tool cannot access this folder, it will fail and that is what prompts the error message. To get around this, you can modify the security descriptors of the folder."

Another [article](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12613-windows-resource-protection-cannot-perform-the-requested-operation#run-icacls-command) suggests the same fix:

"It is possible that System File Checker is failing to scan the system because it cannot access the WinSxS folder due to issues with the WinSxS folder's security descriptors. To run the ICALCS command, open Command Prompt with administrative privileges and execute the "ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs" command."

However, both articles only instruct to enter the "ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs" command and restart the computer and the issue might be fixed. This makes it sound like the command "ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs" actually does something.

So I am wondering, have I misunderstood the instructions of the articles or is there something that I'm missing? Does the command "ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs" actually do something else than just view the permissions of the folder? Is the command safe to execute and how does it affect the system, for example can it be a security risk of some kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That article is pure nonsense.
[icacls](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) works on object.

The command `icacls "C:\demo\example"` does nothing else than
display the permissions currently set on the folder.
For example:

[image]

This means that the command `ICACLS C:\Windows\winsxs` does nothing that needs
a reboot.

On another note, the folder `C:\Windows\winsxs` is an essential Windows folder
and should absolutely not be touched as regarding permissions.
Changing the permissions on this folder can cause serious problems in the future.

Conclusion: Better ignore that article (or at least that part of it).

Comment: On reading the directions; I gather the command being suggested is for fixing it when somebody messes up the permissions on this folder.

Comment: @Joshua: I got the same impression, only it doesn't do that.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It's not searchable, not accessibly for people with poor eyesight or relying on screen readers, and doesn't look good on high DPI screens.

Answer (score 4):

No, the command doesn't do anything unless you tell it *how* to modify the SD. That's something the article forgets to mention.

I have the feeling that it was written based on generic instructions such as "You can use icacls to modify a folder's ACL" – but the article's author didn't understand what they were writing about and assumed that the command would perform all necessary modifications without any further input, which is not the case.

Comment: _"But I followed the instructions and it worked for me!"_ - the author, probably, who probably had an update pending which got applied when they rebooted, or needed a reboot anyway, which fixed their original problem, whatever that was.